# std values of principal component object differs in prcomp and caret

Tags: r, statistics

I was trying Principal Component Analysis in the following data set. I tried through prcomp function  and caret preProcess function.

```
  library(caret)
  library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)

  set.seed(3433)
  data(AlzheimerDisease)
  adData = data.frame(diagnosis,predictors)
  inTrain = createDataPartition(adData$diagnosis, p = 3/4)[[1]]
  training = adData[ inTrain,]
  testing = adData[-inTrain,]

  # from prcomp
  names1 <-names(training)[substr(names(training),1,2)=="IL"]
  prcomp.data <- prcomp(training[,names1],center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
  prcomp.data$sdev

  ## from caret package
  preProcess(training[, names1], method=c("center", "scale", "pca"))$std
```

I was wondering why sdev values differ in the above processes.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first method is giving you standard deviations of 12 principal components (which you can see with `prcomp.data$rotation`).

Also, this is mentioned in the documentation for the `sdev` value:

> the standard deviations of the principal components (i.e., the square
>   roots of the eigenvalues of the covariance/correlation matrix, though
>   the calculation is actually done with the singular values of the data
>   matrix).

The 2nd is giving you standard deviations on the pre-processed input data (hence the variable names associated with each standard deviation).

A small side note -- `caret` PCA's are automatically scaled and centered unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have selected only the variables with substr(names(training),1,2)=="IL" from thedataset , in both the ways. Then when I extract the sdev/std , I was wondering the values should be same.

Comment: @Hack-R, is it possible to extract the standard deviations of the PCs (or the eigenvalues) from `caret`'s ´preProcess´? It seems a bit weird to offer PCA as an option in a function, but then don't make the transformed data nor the eigenvalues accessible. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Harry Right, yes I know. The values should not be the same. The former are the standard deviations *of the principal components* and the latter *of the processed data*.

Comment: @KenS. The normal use of `preProcess` is as an inline transformation option to `train`, e.g. `train(Species~., dat, method = "knn", preProcess=c("pca"), trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))` rather than an independent PCA analysis, which is not the focus of the `caret` package. `princomp` or `prcomp` are strongly preferred for that use case. Having said that, I know that you can get the rotation matrix by using `predict` on a `preProcess` object, i.e. `results <- predict(my_pre_process, my_data); results$rotation`.